# Flutter display DateTime based on mobile device settings

Tags: flutter

I am looking for some guidance on using flutter and taking a UTC datetime from the DB and displaying that time based on mobile devices settings like locale, 24 versus 12 hour time, etc...

I have done dateformating in flutter without an issue, just hoping for some guidance to do it in this manner.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found that if its for display of a UTC pulled from DB just use the DateTime.toLocal()

Then you can do the formatting on the datetime for other items.